# Set substring length with the length of longest data in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing a substring to get all the email address matching a certain Expense Code. Since I don't know ahead of time what will be the max length I always use a way too big int and I wonder if it would affect the performance of the query.

What I need is to get the length of the row with the longest EmployeeEmails data and set the @MAXINT with it

```
DECLARE @MAXINT INT = 2147483646

SELECT 
JOB.JOBNUMBER AS ExpenseCode,
substring(
    (
        Select ',' + LOWER(EMP.ELECTRONICMAILADDRESS) AS [text()]
        From dbo.EMPLOYEE EMP 
            INNER JOIN ITEM on ITEM.ACCESSLEVELNAME = JOB.ACCESSLEVELNAME
        Where LOWER(EMP.NAME2 + '.' + EMP.NAME3) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI = ITEM.NAMEOFUSER
            AND GETDATE() < CASE WHEN EMP.DATEENDEMPLOYMENT = '' THEN '2099-01-01' ELSE EMP.DATEENDEMPLOYMENT END
        ORDER BY EMP.ROWID
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, @MAXINT) EmployeeEmails
FROM JOB
ORDER BY JOB.JOBNUMBER
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `SUBSTRING` use `STUFF`. So instead of the expression:

```
SUBSTRING((SELECT...),2,2147483646)
```

Do:

```
STUFF((SELECT...),1,1,'')
```

`STUFF` is commonly used to strip the first character(s) off of a string ion SQL Server.

Comment: @Cheon do you know that you get reputation points for accepting an answer to your question?   You should try it.